# PostgreSQL Round Function Performance alternative

Tags: postgresql, rounding, database-performance

I'm working to sort out a calculation heavy query and have now moved to focus on the `Focus function` built-in to PostgreSQL.

An example of the part of the select function:

`ROUND(Accepted_Proposals::numeric / NULLIF(student_applications::numeric, 0), 2) AS "% of Accepted Proposals"`

This ratio calculation is one of many, i'm wondering if this function is performance hungry and whether there is a better way of rounding this calculation say only using `::numeric` for both sides of the equation?\

Glad to hear your experience or opinions

Comment: I am pretty sure other things are more expensive than that. Check the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze)` to find the slowest parts

Comment: Operations using `numeric` are much more expensive than operations on `double precision`.